# Select Child entities with condition

Tags: entity-framework

My data structure is given below.

[image]

I have to retrieve the challenge, challenge detail, question and trans question from above structure for challenge id 77 and language id 1.

can anyone let me know the entity framework query.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var challenges = ChallengeDbSet.Where(challenge => challenge.ChallengeId == 77);

var challengeDetails = challenges.ChallengeDetails; 

var questions = challengeDetails.Select(c => c.Question);

var transQuestions = questions.SelectMany(q => q.TransQuestions.Where(t => t.LanguageId == 1));
```

Comment: a very simple question that i could do easily or even anyone can do easily. but can i encapsulate it in 1 Challenge object? or how would i return filtered Challenge record?

Comment: First you ask a question so poorly formulated that it is almost impossible to understand, and then you criticize the only answer in a demeaning way. Mind your manners please.

Comment: In my first edit I wrote what I now believe to be what you asked for, but I went away from that, because it seemed silly to filter further after filtering by challengeId.
Is [this](http://pastebin.com/862mmJ0i) what you are looking for? 
If not, I still have no idea what you are asking.